# get request url after AJAX request

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, view

I have a search page with link `Search?params` but any subsequent search requests are made via Ajax forms using Asp.Net. It makes a request to an action with a different name like `InstantSearch?params` but in the browser I see `Search?params`.

From this page I have a link to another page and I need to save the Url to return back to this page.

But if I had an AJAX request, Request.Url returns `InstantSearch?params`, not the link from browser address bar. And the action from this link returns only a Partial View, so when it returns to the previous URL the page is messed up.

How do I get the link of the previous page, from the browser address bar in Asp.Net, not the actual last requested URL?

While searching we are loading masonry containers like this:

```
$("#main-content-container").load("/Kit/InstantSearch?" + parameters, function() {
        $('#mason-container').imagesLoaded(function() {
            $('#mason-container').masonry({
                itemSelector: '.kit-thumb-container',
                columnWidth: 210,
                isFitWidth: true,
                gutter: 10
            });


        });
    });
```

Then I'm calling foundation Joyride on same page and need to pass current page URL to return back. Joyride calls onload of the page under this link:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Go to kit details help", "OrderPageHelp", "Kit", new { returnUrl = Request.Url }, new { @style = "font-size:16px;" })
```

The needed page return Url is `Kit/Search?params`, but Request.Url returns that last request when loading masonry with `Kit/InstantSearch?params`.

How can I pass the needed Url without hard-coding it?

Comment: You need to show your code/HTML etc that you have tried. The description of what you want is unclear.

Comment: Actually, I almost found the solution.

I have such action:

Html.ActionLink("Go to help", "PageHelpAction", "HelpController", new { returnUrl = Request.Url }, new { @style = "font-size:16px;" })

Request.Url returns wrong url(from last AJAX request), but JavaScript's location.pathname returns needed result.

Can I pass that JS variable into Html.ActionLink as a parameter?

Comment: Nope. You cannot pass a client-side value into the page like that. Again you need to clarify your question and show code, to avoid further down-votes.

Comment: I have edited top post with some code.

Answer (score 0):

So this ones a bit old but I found myself in a similar situation recently and found a quick work around. Posting it in case any one's interested.

You can solve this problem by taking advantage of the TempData class.
Temp Data can be used to store data in between requests. The information will remain as long as the session is active, until you retrieve the data again.

So when the user first loads the page, before the ajax method is triggered, store the data in a variable on the page AND in the TempData("YourVariableName") object. Create the Action Link with the Saved URL. When the ajax request is fired it will overwrite the value in Request.URL. So, Check for a value in the TempData("YourVariableName"), if it is there, use that value AND Reset the TempData("YourVariableName") value. This will keep the original value of the page URL even after many ajax requests have been triggered. Code in Visual Basic:

```
@Code
    Dim LastURL As String = ""
    If Not TempData("LastURL") Is Nothing Then
        LastURL = TempData("LastURL")
        TempData("LastURL") = LastURL
    Else
        LastURL = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
        TempData("LastURL") = LastURL
    End If
End Code
```

And pass the value stored in the LastURL variable as a parameter to your action link.